PrimeVue OrgChart - how to show last nodes in vertical table?
in PrimeVue OrgChart (https://tailwind.primevue.org/organizationchart/), I need to display last "leafs" of tree structured data as list (like table rows) rather than horizontal table cells.
That "last leafs" have type 'device';
Does someone know how to do it?
thanks!
Y

Disclaimer: I'm a developer from BALKAN App
OrgChart JS has built-in functionallity to display the last "leafs" vertically as "table rows"

